# C++ What datatype is a thread_id and can it assigned to a variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-synchronization

I am curious what datatype a thread is, and if it is assignable to a variable and advisable/useful to do so.

Using the `#include <thread>` library.

Comment: Which threading library are you using?

Comment: Type is [std::thread::id](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id). Yes it [can be assigned](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id). When you are curious, use search ;)

Comment: Ah, I did, and that seemed... recurrent maybe? Like thread::id == thread::id? Does that mean that specific member of thread is also an ADT within thread? I thought maybe it was closer to a primitive datatype?

Comment: It is a class. [Nested class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) of [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). It has some of the [operators overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), as described in the reference, so it looks like a primitive type. What is ADT?

Comment: @Drop OOOOOOoooooohhhh.... That makes so much sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @Drop Put that down as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Drop ADT = Abstract Data Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`std::thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) is a class REPRESENTING an individual thread of execution.

It is not itself an operating system thread.  It just represents it.

You can create an object of type thread:

```
thread t1(foo);
```

You can move-construct such an object and you can move-assign such an object:

```
thread t2,t3;
t3=thread(foo);   // move assignement t3 start function foo() now
t2=move(t3);      // t2 takes over what t3 was representing
```

But you can't copy a thread:

```
//t2=t3;          // not possible to copy threads; you have to move them
```

The identification of a thread can be done via a value of type [`thread::id`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/id/) type (implementation dependent type).  However there's also a `thread::native_handle_type` returned by [`native_handle()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/native_handle/) that can (if supported by implementation) return an identifier that you could use for OS specific functions

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/By4eGF)